# Alarms lost if the phone is in blocked status

Tags: notifications, alarm, firefox-os

I'm developing an app for firefox OS and I have a problem with alarms. The alarms don't fire if the phone is blocked.

The problem appear when the phone is in block status, because the notification desktop doesn't fire. But the APP is on background when you unblock the phone, but nothing happen.

**EDIT**

**Solution in code. Then, I think the problem is disappeared.**

I can add the alarms with this function:

```javascript
// the solution for the app working right is writting this window.onload function
window.onload = function() {
    function addAlarm(){
            // Data alarm will be fire
            var myDate  = new Date();

            myDate.setMinutes(myDate.getMinutes()+1 );

            // information for alarm
            var data    = {
              foo: "bar"
            }

            var request = navigator.mozAlarms.add(myDate, "ignoreTimezone", data);

            request.onsuccess = function () {
              console.log("La alarma ha sido programada");
            };

            request.onerror = function () { 
              console.log("Ha ocurrido un error: " + this.error.name);
            };
    }

   //That get the alarm event to fire the alarm and also add a desktop notification. 

    navigator.mozSetMessageHandler("alarm", function (mozAlarm) {
      console.log('fired Alarm');
      // function that add a desktop notification
      notifyMe();
      $('#alarmFired').append('<p>alarm fired: '+JSON.stringify(mozAlarm)+'</p>');

    });

}
```

The function for desktop notifications:

```javascript
function notifyMe() {
  var options = {body: "notification body", icon : 'http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/mini/icons/icon_accept.gif'}

  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!", options);
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  // Note, Chrome does not implement the permission static property
  // So we have to check for NOT 'denied' instead of 'default'
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

      // Whatever the user answers, we make sure we store the information
      if(!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }

      // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!", options);
      }
    });
  }

  notification.onclick = function(){
    console.log('clicked notification');
    openApp();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use an answer to post an answer, don't edit it in the question. On the same page: don't use an answer as a comment to say you've answered in your question :). Sounds confusing, but basically just use the question for a question and the answer for and answer, and you'll be allright

Answer (score 0):

Paco,

You could probably make use of the following technique

```javascript
// Log visibility of the app
var logVisibility = document.querySelector("#log-visibility"),
    logVisibilityDisplay = document.querySelector("#log-visibility-display");
if (logVisibility && logVisibilityDisplay) {
    logVisibility.onclick = function () {
        logVisibilityDisplay.style.display = "block";
        logVisibilityDisplay.innerHTML = "I have focus!<br>"
        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
            if (document.hidden) {
                console.log("Firefox OS Boilerplate App is hidden");
                logVisibilityDisplay.innerHTML += "Now I'm in the background<br>";
            }
            else {
                console.log("Firefox OS Boilerplate App has focus");
                logVisibilityDisplay.innerHTML += "I have focus!<br>";
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Combined with requesting Screen Lock like

```javascript
// Keep screen on
var lock = null;
var keepscreen = document.querySelector("#keep-screen-on");
if (keepscreen) {
    keepscreen.onclick = function () {
        if (!lock) {
            lock = window.navigator.requestWakeLock('screen');
            keepscreen.innerHTML = "Remove the lock";
        }
        else {
            lock.unlock();
            lock = null;
            keepscreen.innerHTML = "Keep screen on";
        }
    };
}
```

My idea here is:

1. Add your alarm
2. When your function that fires the alarm gets called, you try requesting lock on the screen (Device can't be locked this way).
3. After your alarm has been shut down (user interaction turning it off), you release screen lock again.

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but that's what I can think of right now.

**EDIT**

Okey, I've searched around a little more and you might want to use wakeLock instead of sreen lock. For more info please check out [Screen WebAPI at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Power_Management)